# Having trouble with sections in UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, nsarray

I have the following code in my search method that updates the tableview.

```
for (int x = 0; x < [array count]; x++) {
//network stuff here
self.searchedReservations = [aSearchObjectType objectsFromServerDictionaries:aResultsArray];
[self.aTableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

Each object in the array represent a section in my table, for most cases the count will be 4, so 4 sections.

Right now, the code is loading the same data for all sections in the table's cells.  Instead of the unique data for each section of the table.

Here is the code that loads the cells.  I'm missing some logic that maps the data to the right section of the table.

```
MyClass *object = [self.searchedReservations objectAtIndex:iIndexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = object.customerFullName;
```

Comment: Are you sure you are setting different sectionsIndex value for each section ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  My numberOfSections methods just returns the count of my array, which works fine.

Comment: You're not doing anything different in each incrementation of your loop - are you sure you don't mean to use 'x' (the loop counter) in your indexSetWithIndex: statement?   That won't necessarily fix things though because you also don't seem to be doing anything section specific in your cell loading code (unless you are refreshing searched reservations somehow on each section within the cell loading code).

Comment: Well I just removed `                [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];
` which wasn't needed since I'm updating each section on the line before that.  I think `searchedReservations` is being refreshed along with the table because of the for loop its in runs for however many objects are in array.

Comment: Also, when I use `x` instead of `0` for indexSetWithIndex, I get this exception: `*** Assertion failure in -[UITableViewRowData rectForHeaderInSection:],`

Comment: Please post your cellForRowAtIndexPath: code.

Comment: I think I need to do something like add each of my array into a larger array, so I have an array of arrays for each section. and each section's array has dictionaries for each cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have the code below in your 'cellForRowAtIndexPath' method:

```
MyClass *object = [self.searchedReservations objectAtIndex:iIndexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = object.customerFullName;
```

Tables are organised into sections, then within each section there are rows.  The rows start at zero again for each section.

If you are on section 0, loading cell 0 this code above is not taking the section number into account, only the row number - so it is loading:

```
[self.searchedReservations objectAtIndex:0]
```

to populate the cell.

When you are on section 1, loading cell 0 in section one, you are retrieving exactly the same value because you are just using the row number.  ie. you're still loading

```
[self.searchedReservations objectAtIndex:0]
```

You may think that you are changing the value of the 'searchedReservations' object between the loading of each section (this is what it looks like you're trying to do in the loop above) but I'm not sure that this is working (as the code the populate searchedReservation doesn't seem to do anything different in each loop counter).  Also the first time the table loads it will run through all of the rows in all of the sections anyway.

I think you need to either use the indexPath.section field as well as the indexPath.row field at the time you are populating the cell to ensure you are setting the appropriate row in the appropriate section.

Also use the debugger to see whats going on in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method and in your loop and make sure that you are getting/using a different 'searchedReservations' object for each incrementation of the loop and that this matches the 'searchedReservations' object in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: I think I need to do something like add each of my array into a larger array, so I have an array of arrays for each section. and each section's array has dictionaries for each cell.  What do you think?